# Library for working with web pages in C#

Tags: c#, .net, http

I'm in search for a library that will let me work with web pages using C# without having to display anything graphically. The library should handle web sites that use JavaScript / AJAX and it should return the correct HTML as if I were viewing the source from within Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: are you looking into some kind of web scraping technology?

Comment: How is a scraper supposed to deal with AJAX/JavaScript content without knowing exactly how to interact with it on any given random site?

Comment: @Gary: Yes. @Mike: Well, I need something that will be able to handle a web page using AJAX to load search results and let me scrape those results.

Comment: how will you input the search request and trigger the ajax request to fetch the results?

Comment: @Michael Shimmins: The website right now that I'm going to scrape doesn't require me to trigger anything except modify the URL to change the search parameters. It, however, loads the results using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. It turns out I don't need a library at all and I can do it with the `WebBrowser` control.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebBrowserDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        public const string TestUrl = "http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/tryit_view.asp?filename=tryajax_first";

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
            wb.Navigate(TestUrl);

            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;

            HtmlElement document = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0];
            HtmlElement button = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")[0];

            Console.WriteLine(document.OuterHtml + "\n");

            button.InvokeMember("Click");

            Console.WriteLine(document.OuterHtml);           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to de-reference your event handler when you clean up the form, in case your 'app' gets bigger.

Comment: @kitchen: I'm pretty sure DocumentCompleted will be called once the initial load is completed, not once the subsequent AJAX call has completed.  Have you had success with this?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, it works when the AJAX call completes. 

@George: This is just a demo, the actual app is cleaner/more proper :)